# call from java the kotlin's function -> lambda expressions are not supported in -source 1.7

Tags: android, kotlin

In my android project

in app/build.gradle:

```
android {
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8

    }

    compileSdkVersion 29
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.1.1"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

        // Enabling multidex support.
        multiDexEnabled true
```

and in Kotlin code:

```
object TransportService {

      fun test() {
            getAgentsListSync<List<AgentProfile>>()
        }

        fun <T> getAgentsListSync(): TransportResponse {

            }
        }
}
```

Nice it's work fine. But when I try to call `getAgentsListSync` from java like this:

```
TransportService.INSTANCE.getAgentsListSync<List<AgentProfile>>();
```

I get compile error:

```
MyFragment.java:266: error: lambda expressions are not supported in -source 1.7
        TransportResponse transportResponse = TransportService.INSTANCE.getAgentsListSync<List<AgentProfile>>();
                                                                                                               ^
  (use -source 8 or higher to enable lambda expressions)
```

Comment: Use JDK 1.8 for your project

Comment: @AshokKumar I use JDK 1.8, but it not help

Answer (score 1):

Please try to add this in the module script:

```
android {
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = 1.8
        targetCompatibility = 1.8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
}
```